# Newline code at designtime in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, newline, design-time

Using C#

I know that I can enter a newline into a string with Environment.NewLine, but what if I would like to do this to a string that is part of a control at design time? Is there any way to do this?

For example, I would like to have a bit of multi-line tool-tip text set up at design time.  If I set up said text programmatically I can add new lines in and that works and I end up with a multi-line tool-tip.  But I cannot figure out how to enter a newline into a string of text that is part of a property in design mode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

On Text Property Click on the button to the rightmost.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer, if this is a control that you've made yourself, you won't by default see that drop-down. You need to add it yourself. In order to have a string property include the drop down for entering multi-line text data, you need to give it an editor attribute, for example:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    [Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Which will then show the drop-down. This requires you to add a reference to the `System.Design.dll` in your references though.